# Why does the Double.parseDouble() function round here?

Tags: java, parsing, double, decimal, rounding

Some examples:

```
double a = Double.parseDouble("53.82233040000000557");
System.out.println(a);
output: 53.822330400000006

double b = Double.parseDouble("53.82274970000000280");
System.out.println(b);
output: 53.8227497
```

Why are they getting rounded and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You can use a BigDecimal instead if you really need that accuracy

Comment: You've left out an important thing above: How you're getting that output.

Comment: ...but assuming you're using something that outputs the double as a string: The standard way to converting IEEE-754 floating point numbers to strings is to only output as many digits as are needed to differentiate the actual value of the number from the values on either side of it that can be represented. So even though the number may have more significant places than `53.8227497`, only `53.8227497` is needed to differentiate that number from the representable ones on either side.

Comment: I got the output by using System.out.println().

Comment: The default conversion for printing a double is `Double.toString`. For each double X, there is a set of decimal fractions that parseDouble would convert to X. toString picks the shortest. You can get the full story, with no rounding, using `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(b));`. More usefully, you can use `DecimalFormat ` to control how many digits are  displayed.